# How to exclude deleted objects in a clean() function on a model/form using inline_formsety

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with a custom clean function to make sure no two `DateRange` overlap:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_range = DateRangeField()

    def clean(self):
        error_dict = {}

        if MyModel.objects.exclude(id=self.id).filter(
            date_range__overlap=self.date_range):

            error_dict['date_range'] = ValidationError(
            'Range can not overlap with an existing period.',
            code='overlap_period')

        if error_dict:
             raise ValidationError(error_dict)
```

This works, but if I use `inline_formset` to submit more than one record at a time and delete a record that would remove the conflict (whilst updating others), the `ValidationError` still raises.

This is because the `filter` function is done on the existing records, not the new updated ones.

How can I amend the `filter` to exclude deleted objects in the `inline_formset`? Should I be doing a clean on the form instead? If so, how do I reference deleted objects?

Comment: Instead of deleting the object , don't you think you should tell the user that date range is overlapping and give user option to modify date in the form.

Comment: Thanks, that is the purpose of the `clean` function in Django; `ValidationError` returns a user-friendly prompt in the UI

Comment: ok , so you want to delete the object from the database which has the same date and add a new object ?

Comment: @Neeraj Yes, and validate the form assuming the deletion removes the conflict

Comment: I suggest you use , model clean method and not the form clean method, run the date query in model clean method and if the object is present in the databse , delete it and save the new one.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: @Neeraj As above, that won't work because `filter` works on existing records...

Comment: I think , I have not understood the question. Will try with an example. Assume you have an existing record for date 01Jan21 in the database and user is adding 5 more records of various dates and one of them is 01Jan21. So you want to delete the existing record of 01Jan21 from the database and let the user add all 5 new records , is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the logic on top of the deleted_objects you get from the formset. For this reason, it is easier to implement this logic in the formset, as in the `clean()` method of the model you have visibility on the single current instance (and not the full set of new upcoming instances).

In the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet.deleted_objects) it is explained how to deal with `deleted_objects`

```
instances = formset.save(commit=False)
for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
    # ... your logic here
```

As you can see in the example, you can intercept the deleted objects in order to create the desired logic of validation.

Comment: so override the formset `save()` to perform a validation?

Comment: Yes, this is the simpler way in my opinion, and you can raise the ValidationError there too

Comment: Please let me know if you any issue with the implementation, I'm happy to help